# Location.getCurrentPositionAsync() not compatible with a promise race?

Tags: react-native, async-await, promise, expo, settimeout

I have a findMe button i've created and I can't get a function working to timeout the fetch request after x seconds.

The problem:
The catch block in the OnFindMe function is being triggered immediately (even if I put 10 seconds on the timeout).

I implement it like this:

```
const onFindMe = async () => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true);
            let currentLoco = await fetchWithTimeout(
                Location.getCurrentPositionAsync(),
                10,
                badConnection
            );

            if (!currentLoco) throw new Error("Timeout when fetching location");
            setIsLoading(false);
            setPosition(positionObjectCreator(currentLoco));
        } catch (err) {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setError(err);
            couldntFindYourPosition();
        }
    };
```

My timeout function looks like this:

```
export async function fetchWithTimeout(request, TIMEOUT_SEC, alertFunction) {
    try {
        const res = await Promise.race([request, timeout(TIMEOUT_SEC)]);
        return res;
    } catch (e) {
        
        alertFunction();
    }
}

const timeout = function (s) {
    return new Promise(function (_, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            reject(
                new Error(`Request took too long! Timeout after ${s} second`)
            );
        }, s * 1000);
    });
};
```

And this is the component that should be called upon time out (but the catch block is triggered before it gets this far).

Thanks in advance!!!

```
export const badConnection = () => {
    Alert.alert(
        "aww shucks!",
        "Your internet connection is a bit dodgy, so this feature doesn't work at the moment",
        [
            {
                text: "OK",
                style: "ok",
            },
        ]
    );

    return (
        <View>
            <Button title={"Dodgy internet"} onPress={badConnection} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

UPDATE:

Here is an example of where I have used the fetchWithTimeout and it works as intended, in a different tab, with a different function being called, I have set the timeout at 0.01s to ensure it times out:

```
export const geoCoder = async (searchTerm) => {
  
    let gpsArray = await fetchWithTimeout(
        Location.geocodeAsync(searchTerm),
        0.01,
        badConnection
    );
    return gpsArray;
};
```

But when I substitute in the Location.getCurrentPositionAsync() into the above function, and leave the timeout at 0.01 seconds, the timeout function doesnt work....

```
export const geoCoder = async (searchTerm) => {
  
    let gpsArray = await fetchWithTimeout(
        Location.getCurrentPositionAsync(),
        0.01,
        badConnection
    );
    return gpsArray;
};
```

It simply runs as if the timeout function isnt there, and it fetches the currentPosition.

Comment: So maybe `Location.getCurrentPositionAsync()` returns an immediately rejected promise? What is the error you get in the `catch` block?

Comment: The `try`/`catch` in `fetchWithTimeout` seems pointless. Don't you want the error to propagate?

Comment: @Bergi The error reads: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]. Not sure what to make of it tho. If I remove the fetchWithTimeout try/catch the result is the same, immediate trigger of the catch block in OnFindMe...... thanks!

Comment: Oh. Then use a debugger to find out *which* of the functions you are calling is `undefined`

Comment: @Bergi So its the fetchWithTimeout function which is coming back as undefined. But as soon as I change the function that that function is calling (Location.getCurrentPositionAsync() for any other api call).... it calls it with no problems.

Comment: How did you `import` the `fetchWithTimeout` function in your module? Please post the entire code of the failing call, as well as the code of the working call.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I've added a bit more info down below, hopefully this helps, but if not, then I can come up with a workaround, so we don't waste any more time on it.